# Element.setAttribute only reflects on console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I'm really new to Web Development. While experimenting with a little JavaScript in HTML, I tried to change the content of an element. When I execute the code below, I get "Updated Content" in the console which is the desired outcome. However, the content inside of the popover does not update.

Why does it only update on the console and not the website?

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  document.getElementById('rex').setAttribute('data-bs-content', 'Updated Content');
  console.log(document.getElementById('rex').getAttribute('data-bs-content'));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a id='rex' href="#" title="Header" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-bs-content="Content">Click</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is your bootstrap dependency and the bootstrap library for the scripts

Comment: I didn't include it in this post to keep it concise. But I have edited the post to include it all just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Looking at your updated code, it seems to be working for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: works for me fine too. The attribute has changed according to the dev tools inspector.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. I have tried using the incognito mode and also disabling all extensions as well

@tacoshy did the popover get updated on your end?

Comment: Are you really just want to change the `attribute` or do you actually try to change the `innerHTML`?

Comment: I'm planning to change the attribute of the element. I have yet to read about `innerHTML` yet. I'll try to do that and update it here.

Comment: It looks like it's an order of operations thing. You're updating the content after you run the popover code, so it's showing the current data and then changing the data, which is why it shows in the console but not the popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not certain what all you're looking to update, but have a look at this.  I didn't change anything in your html.  I'm creating an on click binding for the #rex link, and it updates several things... my comments are below.  I'm also using only jquery syntax.  What you posted is kind of a mix and match of jquery and some pure javascript.  You'll help yourself a lot early on paying attention to the difference, but for now since Bootstrap requires jquery its not that big of a deal.

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#rex', function() {
    $(this).text('Updated Content');                          //text of the anchor
    $(this).attr('data-bs-content', 'Updated Content');       //text of the popover
    $(this).popover('show');                                  //trigger popover to show
    // $(this).popover('toggle');                             //or use a toggle
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otzyd54h/

Comment: I apologize if I did not make myself clear. I wanted to change the content of the popover body which corresponds to your 3rd line. It worked perfectly! 

Thank you for the bonus codes to update the different elements too. I am still unclear about the differences between jQuery & JavaScript. The reason I code the way I did is that I'm following a Udemy tutorial called "Django Masterclass: Build 5 Real World Django Projects" This code is written on Lecture 100.

His code works no problem which made me confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the content that appears after the popup is already visible, you need to update the popup itself:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('popover-body')[0].textContent = 'Updated Content';
```